# How can I get the base (last part) of a URL?

Tags: c#

I have URL's like the following:

```
www.abc.def.xxx
www.abc.xxx
www.abc.def.ghi.yy
```

I need to find some way of getting the base "xxx" or "yy" when the URL is different. Can anyone think of a way I can do this with c#

Comment: do you mean the top level domain?

Comment: For `www.apple.com.au`, do you want the `.au` or the `.com.au`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split it on `.`:

```
string url = "www.abc.def.ghi.yy";
string lastPart = url.Split(new char[] {'.'}).Last()
```

Or using Regex:

```
Regex exp = new Regex(@".*\.");
string lastPart = exp.Replace("a.a.a.a.xxx", "");
```

Or just being stupid:

```
string lastPart = new string("www.abc.def.ghi.yy".ToCharArray().Reverse().TakeWhile(i => i != '.').Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: tried the first and had some error messages: Error 24 The type or namespace name 'Char' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I added "using System: and then get another error: Error message: Error 22 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: sorry, don't capitalize the C in Char, so `char` and you will need `using System.Linq;` for `.Last()`

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably be best off using a regular expression for this but one simple way to do it is like this:

```
String str = "www.abc.def.xxx";
int lastPosition = str.LastIndexOf(".");
String baseURL = str.Substring(lastPosition + 1, str.Length - lastPosition - 1);
```

Comment: This gives me an array out of bounds exception. I am not sure but is the 2nd parameter of Substring not supposed to be the length of the characters you want to select?

Comment: Ah sorry. I messed up the indexing. I'll fix it.